# Given a Biased Coin yielding a Flip Sequence, what is the expected number of even palindromes?

Tags: probability, expected-value

This is from a review of an exam.

You continue to play with one of your biased Vegas quarters by flipping it $2k > 0$ times in
a row. You write down these flips as a string of H and T. Recall from the earlier problem
that the probability any flip is H is $2/3$.

(a) Give an expression for the probability that the flip sequence is an even palindrome.

This should certainly be an expression written in terms of $k$.

(b) Even palindromes occur as a substring five times in the flip sequence TTHHTT: once
as the whole string TTHHTT, once each with the substrings THHT and HH. And then
there are two occurrences of TT, one starting at the first flip and one starting at the
fifth flip.
Give an expression for the expected number of even palindromes that occur as substrings within $2k > 0$ flips of the biased coin.

Comment: What have you tried?  The usual first step would be to work this out explicitly for small $k$.  Perhaps a pattern will emerge.  In any case, you will need a number of examples to test whatever general formula you eventually come up with.

Comment: Ahm ... Why do you specifically want the palindromes to be *even*? Why do you want the coin to be *biased*? Why should the expression be in terms of $2k$ rather than $k$? I am just a bit suspicious that this contrived statement of the problem may be coming from some sort of math contest? Or exam? - If yes, which one? If not, where is the motivation coming from to state it exactly as you stated it?

Comment: @StinkingBishop This problem was given in an exam that I got 0 points for and I'm reviewing the problem to see if I could have done anything differently and i couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: Why do you say the biased coin gives a probability of H *two*-thirds of the time? The example TTHHTT looks more like *one*-third.

Comment: @user877105, it might help if you stated the problem *exactly* as it appeared in the exam. What you currently have in the body of the OP is not a question, and the question in the title doesn't contain enough information to formulate an answer. (I,e., is the exam problem really looking for a general formula for a coin that lands H with probability $p$ and gets flipped $2k$ times, or is just asking for $k=3$?)

Comment: @BarryCipra I edited my original post to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part (a), it is useful to calculate how often two independent throws land with the same value. This is $(2/3)^2+(1/3)^2=5/9$. Now, if the coin was thrown $2k$ times, it will be an even permutation if and only if the pairs of throws $(k,k+1), (k-1,k+2),\ldots,(1,2k)$ all coincide, which happens with probability $(5/9)^k$.

For (b), I will not do the work all the way up to the end, but will show a hint what needs to be done. We will try to use *linearity of expectation*. For two indices $i,j$ such that $1\le i<j\le 2k$ and $j-i$ is odd, we will first calculate the expected number of palindromes starting precisely at $i$ and ending precisely at $j$. Because there can be only one or zero of those (depending precisely on whether this subsequence is a palindrome or not), the expectation is, as per (a): $E_{ij}=(5/9)^\frac{j-i+1}{2}$.

Thus, the total expectation of the number of even palindromes is:

$$E=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}i,j\\1\le i<j\le 2k\\j-i\text{ odd}\end{array}}E_{ij}=\sum_{\begin{array}{c}i,j\\1\le i<j\le 2k\\j-i\text{ odd}\end{array}}(5/9)^\frac{j-i+1}{2}$$

Now all that it takes is to do the summation, which can be done in various ways.